# Add action filter to [ApiController] annotated controller's actions only?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Before Core, when the controllers for MVC and Web API were separate, it was easy to target a a global action at one framework or the other. Now with `mvcOptions.Filters.Add<T>();` it'll apply across your MVC view rendering actions and you're API-only actions.

I can see roughly that when you use `[ApiController]` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#apicontroller-attribute)), you're opted in to several conventions/behaviours, but it's not super clear how/if I could add to that convention easily. Potentially I need to create my own additional `ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider`, like the one [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs)? I'm looking for something a little simpler, like `mvcOptions.ApiConvention.Filters.Add(x)`.

Another approach is to have all my API controllers inherit my own `ApiControllerBase` and annotate that, but I'd prefer to extend the convention if possible.

It'd also be nice to go the other way without having to have a `MvcControllerBase` either that's for views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in extensibility for the `[ApiController]` conventions that I know of, but you can achieve what you're looking for with the [application model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/application-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Here's an example implementation of an `IControllerModelConvention` that looks for the `[ApiController]` attribute, which you can fill in with your specific implementation:

```cs
public class ExampleControllerModelConvention : IControllerModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(ControllerModel controllerModel)
    {
        if (controllerModel.Attributes.OfType<ApiControllerAttribute>().Any())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can register this convention in `Startup.ConfigureServices` or *Program.cs* for .NET 6+:

```cs
// Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new SampleControllerModelConvention());
});
```

```cs
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(new SampleControllerModelConvention());
});
```

The [`IsApiController`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ApplicationModels/ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider.cs#L116-L126) method in the `ApiBehaviorApplicationModelProvider` class you linked to handles the check a little differently:

```cs
private static bool IsApiController(ControllerModel controller)
{
    if (controller.Attributes.OfType<IApiBehaviorMetadata>().Any())
    {
        return true;
    }

    var controllerAssembly = controller.ControllerType.Assembly;
    var assemblyAttributes = controllerAssembly.GetCustomAttributes();
    return assemblyAttributes.OfType<IApiBehaviorMetadata>().Any();
}
```

This implementation supports the `[ApiController]` attribute being applied to the assembly the controller lives in. You likely don't need this if you're also using Views, but it's worth noting the difference in this approach.